# Plone 4.2 custom theme administrator javascript not working

Tags: plone

I have problem with my plone site administration, when I apply my own template then the front end side customized as I want, but the administration part javascript and other functionality  like drop down visual html editor is not working. Please any body help me to solve this problem

Version Overview

- Plone 4.3 (4305)
- CMF 2.2.7
- Zope 2.13.19
- Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58) [GCC 4.7.2]
- PIL 1.7.8 (Pillow)

Comment: Edit your question to describe 'my own template' in more detail, particularly things that might affect JavaScript e.g. Diazo rules, your own JavaScript. Does your JS console display any errors? The more info you provide, the better your chance of receiving a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Diazo, then you probably need to add this to the rules in rules.xml:

```
<before theme-children="/html/head" content="/html/head/script" />
```